Removing Windows partitions after installing and configuring Ubuntu
I have a dual boot system (originally Windows-only, but I installed Ubuntu 22.04, now upgraded to 24.04). Here's the current partition table as reported by cdisk:
 Disk: /dev/sda
                              Size: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
                             Label: gpt, identifier: 1F801740-93A4-4AA3-B70E-B68673402A87

Device                        Start               End           Sectors          Size Type
/dev/sda1                      2048            206847            204800          100M EFI System
/dev/sda2                    206848            239615             32768           16M Microsoft reserved
Free space                   239616        1533048831        1532809216        730.9G
/dev/sda4                1952479232        1953521663           1042432          509M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5                1533048832        1952479231         419430400          200G Linux filesystem
Free space               1953521664        1953525134              3471          1.7M 

As can be seen my Linux partition is only 200G. But I deleted the Windows primary partition which is about 730G. I'd like to safely nuke the other Windows partitions and make this an exclusive Ubuntu box without losing any data (this is paramount since I have a lot of settings and customizations that I'd like to preserve)
I have two approaches in mind (not clear on how to go about on either though):

Setup a new disk and follow the steps in This Question. This seems unnecessarily complicated for what I want to accomplish though.
Some how remove all other partitions and move data from the existing partition to the newly expanded (to occupy the entire disk sans the boot partition). Basically, expand the partition to include all the free space and move the data to start at the beginning sector of the new partition.

Can someone familiar with this type of changes guide me through, please? I found some decades old posts that kind of touch on these subjects, but I'm sure there are more modern and safe utilities to deal with in 2024.

Back in Floppy days, system was on a: and data on b:. When hard drives with partitions I had c: as system & d: as data. With XP & Ubuntu I had a shared NTFS data partition and Linux only ext4 partition. You can just create one or more large data partitions as ext4, give yourself ownership & permissions & copy data. You also can link data back into /home so data looks like in /home but really in data partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2488332&p=14149243#post14149243
